# GA as RequireJS dependency vs. AdBlock EasyPrivacy list

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, requirejs, adblock

I have an app (angular, d3, etc) that I'm loading up with require.js. Google Analytics and some other scripts that are blocked by AdBlock's EasyPrivacy list are in the dependency chain, which means the app won't load if the user has it enabled.

I know there are fallback paths if I don't run the optimizer on my scripts to wrap them up, but is there any way to either fall back if they're blocked, or to sniff for the ad blocker and conditionally load a separate config, while still being able to optimize and wrap my scripts?

Maybe something like:

```
define(function () {
  try {
    var something = require('//path/to/ga');
  } catch (e) {
    return require('fallback');
  }
  return something;
});
```

using that as the dependency to load GA?

Would something like this work? Is there something I'm missing, or some better way? Can I sniff for AdBlock but only if it's blocking analytics, and load accordingly?

Comment: You can check for the presence of an object belonging to ga, 'GoogleAnalyticsObject' I guess. Or check that the 'analytics.js' file has loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After far too long, I figured out that using `:empty` in the r.js config, e.g.

```
paths: {
    googleAnalytics: ":empty",
    ...
}
```

loads the original file(s) called for in `main.js` including callbacks, so I could add the fallback there:

```
paths: {
   googleAnalytics: ['//www.google-analytics.com/analytics', 'ga-fb'],
   ...
}
```

where `ga-fb.js` just loads a script that adds a noop function at `window.ga` to keep from throwing errors when it's called. The `ga-fb.js` can't be folded into the optimized file and will load separately if it's needed.

Probably a beginner-level problem, but I hope this saves someone issues down the road. It was my first project using require.js, so I'm bound to have beginner-level issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can list the google analytics.js URL in your `paths` in require.js config:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    ga: '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics'
  }
});
```

Then inside of an analytics function where you need to access google analytics just call it directly, and have an error function that assigns `window.ga` to a function that always returns undefined:

```
require(['ga'], function(data) {
  window.ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X');
  window.ga('send', 'pageview');
}, function() {
  window.ga = function(){};
});
```